# Building a list dynamically (depending on checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-lists, dynamically-generated

I have the following question:

I have a couple of checkboxes (at the moment 11) and what I want to do now is "building" a list dynamically, depending on the value of the checkboxes, so having something like this:

A user comes, ticks a checkbox and one `li` is appearing, when he ticks the next one, the next `li` is appearing, when he ticks the next one, again one `li` is appearing and so on (when he unticks one of them, the `li` should disappear again). I'm quite sure this can work with JS, but I have no idea how to realize it.
What I have is a `<ul>` and all the checkboxes defined with

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_phone" id="check_phone"/>
<label for="check_phone"><span></span>Phone Number</label>
```

(Every checkbox has it's individual name)
What I think is going to be the biggest problem is creating the list-points dynamically, but I really hope somebody knows how to do this.

What I already thought about is just having 11 list-points in my list, all set to `display:none` and then just setting them to `display:block` when a checkbox is checked, but this will propably not work because I'm using a plugin to resort the list after this, and having 11 list-points, but just 2 visible or anything like that won't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please add the best code that you tried? That code even if wrong might help one as a start-point for giving you an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks pretty straight forward. You should read and follow a few "getting started" tutorials, especially about jquery. Most likely you will yourself be able to implement this afterwards. That is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very quick demo, each time a checkbox is changed it creates all checked list items.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.item').on('change', function() {
  var $list = $('ul#checked').empty();

  $('.item:checked').each(function(index, item) {
   var itemName = $(item).prop('name');
            var text = $('label[for='+itemName+']').text()
   $('<li></li>')
    .text(text)
    .appendTo($list)
   ;
  })

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="item" name="check_phone" id="check_phone"/>
<label for="check_phone"><span></span>Phone Number</label>
<ul id="checked">
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to be the thing I was searching for, because, as I wrote, I don't want to hide or unhide the elements, but having them "dynamically generated". But actually it's not working in my case... I tried you're solution also on a fiddle, and it's working. As tried on fiddle, it's because my syntax of the definition of the Checkboxes looks a bit different (see above). How can I get it working anyway?

Comment: please link the jsfiddle, otherwise I can only guess.

Comment: Working now, thanks for that, but now my "Sortable" plugin is not working any more... It's just including the plugin and calling the sortable function one time (`$('.sortable').sortable();`, having the `ul` given the class sortable), but now it's not working any more, propably because the list changes and at the beginning there are no elements in it... Any ideas?...

Comment: you might need to reinitialize the sort after each change to the list.

Comment: please give it a good go to work out the problem and if you still need help open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("[name^='check_']").click(function(){
    $("li."+ this.name).toggle( this.checked );
});
```

```css
#check_list li{ display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><input type="checkbox" name="check_phone"/>Phone Number</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check_mobile"/>Mobile Number</label>

<ul id="check_list">
  <li class="check_phone">PHONE LI</li>
  <li class="check_mobile">MOBILE LI</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it. You just have to set the names of the list items to be the same as their corresponding checkboxes' names.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
            var current = $(this),
                  linkedListCorrespondingElement = $('#list-id > li[' + current.attr('name') + ']');
            if (current.is(":checked")) {
                 linkedListCorrespondingElement.show();
            } else {
                linkedListCorrespondingElement.hide();
            }
     });
```